# Best answer formats?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I edited this question ([see edit history](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/posts/1026/edit)) to remove strikeouts and to generally, as I saw it, make the answer a little easier to read. The change was approved, but the original author of the answer then rolled the changes back. I have no interest in a roll-back war, but I'm wondering what is considered best practice for this site.

I recognize that each SE community will have different ideas of best practices, so I have no strong feeling on this for this site. That said, I would argue that blog-style strikeouts do not work well in a Q&A format. I would say it clutters the answer, makes it harder to read, and tends to hide (rather than highlight) the important information.

On a similar note, when quoting information on outside pages, should we generally bring the relevant parts (properly cited and linked) into the answer in case the external page disappears or changes or is a link-only answer OK?

Please note, I am in *no way* trying to criticize or flame. I'm just wondering what is considered best practice on this particular SE site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble caused, when I rolled-back to my original answer I did it to preserve the old link and to keep the original meaning of my answer. I was, however, doing it from my cellphone, and the mobile site interface is not very handy for editing, formatting and basically anything except writing down plain text.

I have already corrected my answer to give it a better looking while also keeping all informations that were deleted from the suggested edit.

And, of course, I also had no desire to flame or argue :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. On my side, I was wondering if I was editing out too much..but since you had crossed out the link and said it was outdated...;)

Comment: Right, but it could still be useful for reference. Anyway, everything solved.

Comment: Thanks, @Sekhemty -- appreciate everyone handling this so nicely! :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the edit (removing the strikeouts) was appropriate. The author of the answer in question should have either removed the incorrect text or added an edit to explain the correction. Because there has already been one edit and rollback, I think the best approach in this situation is probably to leave a comment explaining the concern. I have just left a comment along those lines.

That said, thanks for not engaging in a rollback war and bringing this to Meta -- this is the right way to handle the situation.

Answer (score 0):

To me SO and SE all have a similar feel, probably caused by the carry over the experience members going from one site to another.

I actually rejected your edit, as I think that from a certain rep¹, you should trust that a user knows about formatting and does something on purposes. 
My general rule of changing (for myself) is: the higher the rep, the smaller the changes you should make. Obviously other people thought differently and accepted your edits.

Obvious typos and grammatical errors should always be a target for an edit. So are inconsistencies within a post (casing, English vs. American, formatting). 
I also think a user (as original poster or as editor) should be consistent in what they are doing (e.g. blockquoting acronyms in [one post](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/revisions/1038/3), but not in [another](https://ebooks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/182/60), hurts my sense of aesthetics), but that kind of consistency should primarily be ones own responsibility.

¹ <sub>I mean total rep over all the sites, not just here on ebooks, as an indication of a user 'knowing what they are doing'</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't doubt that the original answer had strikeouts on purpose. My point is that I think strikeouts are a bad fit for the Q&A format: an answer should always be easy to read and should simply state the most up-to-date info. I think my edits made the whole thing easier to read and understand. Not everyone will agree; that's fine. But, I'm still wondering: Is it an acceptable format on this site to strikeout - and leave on the page - whole paragraphs rather than removing or _re-writing_ them to reflect the newer info.

Comment: @chaskes I won't argue about whether your changes were better readable or not, that is not relevant to my answer.

Comment: Not trying to argue. :). I appreciate all feedback. Thanks again for replying to the question.

Comment: @chaskes I tend to ask first before doing this kind of changes, particularly if the other has higher rep. That is in my experience a safer approach. I have seen users go nuts, roll-back changes and throw away the child/rubber-duck with the bath water. The edits here tend to be minor, not like [metase] where you sometimes don't recognise your own question after 24 hours ;-)